# Is there a programmable method for calculating the exponent value of a power sum

Tags: python, math, optimization

Say I have an equation:

**a^x + b^x + c^x = n**

Since I know **a**, **b**, **c** and **n**, is there a way to solve for x?

I have been struggling with this problem for a while now, and I can't seem to find a solution online.

My current method is to iterate over X until the left side is "close enough" to n. The method is pretty slow and in an already computationally difficult algorithm.

Example:

**3^x + 5^x + 7^x = 83**

How do i go about solving for x. (2 in this case)
I tried the equation in WolframAlpha and it seems to know how to solve it, but any other program fails to do so.

I probably should also mention that X is not an integer (mostly in 0.01 to 0.05 range in my case).

Comment: You should look for one of the many root finding algorithms out there. @Cute Panda already told you about `spicy.optimize.root`. If you are interested in the mathematical background check out the Wiki article for e. g. the newton method.

Comment: @alexschu98 spicy? ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyPerot Oh, whoops, thank you very much

Comment: are `a,b,c,n >= 0` ? ... I would go for **binary search**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use scipy library. You can install it using command `pip install scipy`

Then, this code will work:

```
from scipy.optimize import root

def eqn(x):
  return 3**x + 5**x + 7**x - 83


myroot = root(eqn, 2)

print(myroot.x)
```

Here, root takes two arguments root(fun, x0) where fun is the function of the equation and x0 is an rough estimate of the root value. For example if you know that your root will fall in range of (0,1) then you can enter 0 as rough estimate.

Also make sure the equation entered in the code is such that R.H.S. is equal to 0.

In our case `3^x + 5^x + 7^x = 83` becomes `3^x + 5^x + 7^x - 83 = 0`

[Reference Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root)

Comment: Subtracting 83 is right. root() finds a root of a function, i.e., value of x for which the function is equal to zero. Thus, you _have to_ subtract 83, otherwise you would solve 3**x + 5**x + 7**x = 0 instead of 83.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to base Python, it is easy enough to implement [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for this problem:

```
from math import log

def solve(a,b,c,n,guess,tol = 1e-12):
    x = guess
    for i in range(100):
        x_new = x - (a**x + b**x + c**x - n)/(log(a)*a**x + log(b)*b**x + log(c)*c**x)
        if abs(x-x_new) < tol: return x_new
        x = x_new
    return "Doesn't converge on a root"
```

Newton's method might fail to converge in some pathological cases, hence an escape valve for such cases. In practice it converges very rapidly.

For example:

```
>>> solve(3,5,7,83,1)
2.0
```

Despite all this, I think that Cute Panda's answer is superior. It is easy enough to do a straight-forward implementation of such numerical algorithms, one that works adequately in most cases, but naive implementations such as the one give above tend to be vulnerable to excessive round-off error as well as other problems. scipy uses highly optimized routines which are implemented in a much more robust way.